# How to Compare GifImageView to a Drawable if they are similar?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have an app that runs a Gif with parts of its Image **SCATTERED** all over the screen but there is this moment where the scattered Image will get to its **ORIGINAL IMAGE**.

The Gif is also clickable.When the app runs, the Gif automatically starts.
When you tap the Gif, the Gif freezes. When you tap it again, the Gif resumes.

What I wanted the user to experience is to stop the image at the moment they combine to become the **ORIGINAL IMAGE**.

I'm having a hard time trying to compare the original image to the current image of the freezed Gif. I hope you can help me.

**Activity :**

```
public class NextActivity extends Activity {

GifImageView image;

int counter =0;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_next);

     image = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_1);




    image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(counter%2==0){

                image.setFreezesAnimation(true);
                ((GifDrawable)image.getBackground()).stop();


                if(image.getBackground().getCurrent().getConstantState() == ContextCompat.getDrawable(NextActivity.this,R.drawable.lvl_1).getConstantState())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(NextActivity.this,"GOOD JOB!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(NextActivity.this,"ALMOST!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                counter++;


            }
            else{
                image.setFreezesAnimation(false);

                ((GifDrawable)image.getBackground()).start();
                counter++;
            }
        }
    });




}


}
```

Comment: note down total time and use Thread  when it become original Image stop it.!

Comment: that's what comes up to mind. I was thinking to make my code shorter. If ever I can't do this with comparing images, I guess I'll do the time. Could you suggest some links with CountUp timer that has pause/resume button?

Answer (score 0):

You can use thread.

```
boolean flag = false;
Handler mHandler = new Handler();

pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(flag)
            PauseThread();
            flag=!flag;
            }
        });
resume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        animation.play();
        flag=!flag;
    }
    });


public void PauseThread()
{

  new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10000); // 10 sec 
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                // Write your code here to update the UI.
                                    animation.stop();
                                      //flag=!flag;
                                }
                            });
                        } catch (Exception e) {}
                    }
                }
            }).start();
}
```

Comment: Yes this is also what I did. I'll consider this as an answer if you can provide me how to pause and resume the timer in the onClickListener.

Comment: hmmmm. what I wanted was to stop the timer and the Gif. in this example this doesn't work.